# Unable to override unit_price for an order_item

Tags: commerce

I'm trying to override the `unit_price` for an `order_item` based on various selected options when adding to the cart. The product is configured at $0.00. So I do a `$order_item->setUnitPrice(new Price(9.99, 'USD'), TRUE)->save()`, add a status message to the messenger, and then redirect to `/products`. If I do a `\Drupal::logger('testy test')->info(print_r($order_item->toArray(), TRUE))` after setting the price, I see that the price and the override flag have been set. If I check the `commerce_order_item` table before doing anything else in the UI, I see that the price and override flag have not been set, or have been reverted. I'm thinking the latter, because if I manually set the fields in the database and rebuild the cache, those changes get reverted.

At the same time, I am able to override the `unit_price` for an `order_item` of a different `order_item_type` and `product_variation_type`, but I don't see anything in those configs that would affect the ability to override the price.

What am I missing?